# What does an Angulars Js factory return?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I can't understand how factory returns an object of itself.For example like :

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.factory('myfactory',function(){


     var foo = {};
     factory.message = function(){

         //do something

      }


     return foo;

 });
```

Now,I can call this factory's methods from my controller like `myfactory.message`
But how is the factory constructor returning an object of itself.Does it have to do with angular's implementation of factory or am I missing some javascript basics here?

Comment: http://ngtutorial.com/learn/factory.html

Comment: the returned object is NOT an instance of the factor -- as described by the foo; ah ok, in your case it is... because you are returning it.

Comment: the function is supposed to be a factory, which produces something. and your factory can produce a value, a service, ...etc... in your case you just name an object a factory (just a naming).

Comment: @NoypiGilas-I edited my code.now please read my question again..I think you were confusing my real question with something else

Comment: you inject "myfactory" to fully injectables as shown by the foo, and then angular will call the factory function, then your factory function will create a new object -- and returns it; which by the way you named 'factory (but not necessarily);

Comment: here's an example of a factory creating a service, might be clearer for you... http://ngtutorial.com/learn/service.html#/toc_3

Answer (score 1):

This is pure javascript functionality.

A new empty literal object is being created called 'factory' it is a different object.  The line "var factory = {}" is what creates the object. From there you can add functions (methods) on this new object e.g. "message".

I haven't played with Angular for a while, but the only thing that it does for you is assign this new returned object to the name you specified 'myfactory'

The fact that the variable is named factory inside the function is what might be confusing you. the name could be anything like "foo" or "builder" and it would work them same.

**In response to your last comment see below about the factory returning an instance of "itself"**

The factory constructor is not returning an instance of 'itself'.  The factory method takes (in this case) two parameters a "name" and function. The function returns an object (with methods,properties etc.) that provide the desired functionality.

All that The factory method on myapp (angular internals) is doing is  assigning 'name' to the object that is returned from the function and making it available to your controllers.

Don't get hung up on the idea of angular returning a 'factory'. Angular just needs a piece of code (a provider) that provides some functionality to your controllers.
For example a service could be created like this:

```
function Houdini(){
    this.doIt = function(){
    alert("abracadabra");
    };
}

myapp.factory("mrMagic", function doSomethingGreat(){
  return new Houdini()
})
```

Later in your controller you could do

mrMagic.doIt().

Comment: I know that 'foo' part.My question is how is the returned object an instance of the factory?

Comment: the answer is simple: it is not

Answer (score 0):

As you can note from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers),
`Note: All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs.`

So when you declare some factory - you declare object which will be returned and injected with [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

By the way, that all is described also in documentation for `services` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) :

`Angular services are:`

`- Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.`
 `- Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.`

#### Edit:

From point of view `JavaScript` such happens when you copy `Object` by link, for example:

```
var obj1 = {name: 'Alex', id: 2};
var obj2 = obj1;
console.log(obj1.name) // 'Alex'
console.log(obj2.name) // 'Alex'
obj2.name = 'Max';
console.log(obj2.name) // 'Max'
console.log(obj1.name) // 'Max'
```

So you can check the same in angular like:

```
.factory('myfactory', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        someArray: [1, 2]
    }
}])
```

then in controllers:

```
.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'myfactory', function ($scope, myfactory) {
    myfactory.someArray[0] = 100500;
})

.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'myfactory', function ($scope, myfactory) {
    console.log(myfactory.someArray[0]); /* if this controller is initialized after 'ctrl1' - you will see in console '100500' instead of '1' */
})
```

By the way, `.factory()` is a function which returns an `Object`. Inside of angular when you inject some service - `.factory()` callback is called the first time and creates instance of returned object. After angular returns everywhere just **ONE** instance of this `Object`. Not its copies.

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: you missed my question.My question is how come the object we return from a factory is the factory itself?

shouldn't it be just a variable we are returning? How come it is a reference to the factory itself?

Comment: @PradeepSaini: You are wrong. Factory is a function. You just create a pair `value` - `function`. `function` is called when you inject your value the first time anywhere and creates instance of returned `Object`. After function finished working the first time - you have a returned from angular instance of  `Object` with just the same name value like a factory names

Answer (score 0):

the question itself is wrong. here's what you are actually doing, see "theFactory" there -- that is the factory... you never did return a factory instance.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.factory('myfactory',function theFactory(){


     var service = {};

     service.message = function(){

         //do something

      }


     return service;

 });
```

see more examples: [ngtutorial.com/learn/service.html#/toc_3](http://ngtutorial.com/learn/service.html#/toc_3)